# More aces than tens

Tags: probability, card-games

A hand of 13 cards is dealt from a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that it contains more aces than tens? How does this probability change when you have the information that the hand contains at least one ace?

If

$X=[$# aces in hand$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X=x)=\frac{\binom{4}{x}\binom{52-4}{13-x}}{\binom{52}{13}}$ and

$Y=[$# tens in hand$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\frac{\binom{4}{y}\binom{52-4}{13-y}}{\binom{52}{13}}$, I should have $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=\sum_{y=0}^{x}\frac{\binom{4}{y}\binom{48}{13-y}}{\binom{52}{13}}\cdot \sum_{x=y+1}^{4}\frac{\binom{4}{x}\binom{48}{13-x}}{\binom{52}{13}}=\sum_{y=0}^{4}\frac{\binom{4}{y}\binom{48}{13-y}}{\binom{52}{13}}\frac{\binom{4}{y}\binom{48}{13-y}}{\binom{52}{13}}$.

Thus if $X\geq 1$ we obtain $\mathbb{P}(X>Y|X\geq 1)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X>Y\cap X\geq 1)}{\mathbb{P}(X\geq 1)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X>Y)}{\sum_{x=1}^{4}\frac{\binom{4}{x}\binom{48}{13-x}}{\binom{52}{13}}}$,

where $\mathbb{P}(X>Y|X\geq 1)=\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ because if $X<1\Rightarrow X=0\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(0>Y)=0$.

Is it correct?

Comment: If I understand your working, you are considering X and Y independent which they are not. You have to choose $1 \le n \lt 8$ cards out of 8 (Aces + Tens) in such a way that there are more aces than tens. You have to choose $(13-n)$ cards from rest $44$ cards.

Comment: @MathLover So is it simply $\sum_{k=j+1}^{4}\frac{\binom{4}{k}\binom{4}{j}\binom{52-4-4}{13-k-j}}{\binom{52}{13}}$ with $j$ number of tens and $k$ number of aces?

Comment: That is correct. $j = 0, 1, 2, 3$